# How to apply workflow to items that are already in a list?

Tags: list, workflow, email

Ok.  I have a list of Asset Items.  I want to write a workflow to send out an email when the item's warranty will expire within 30 days.  I know that when I write the workflow it is triggered either manually or when and items is created or modified.  Besides going to each item in the list how can I apply the workflow to items that are already in the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no OTB support for your requirement. However there is a possibile with a work around by making the items updated with a small technique.

Here are the articles explains the technique to achieve your goal.

http://spcycle.blogspot.in/2012/01/kicking-off-workflow-on-entire-list.html

[Apply workflow to existing item using Sharepoint Designer?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/105943/apply-workflow-to-existing-item-using-sharepoint-designer)